# How to measure the total number of heap bytes used in Unix?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I want to build a test client that estimates both space and time complexity of an algorithm implementation (basically what the autograder in Algorithms I & II courses on Coursera does), but for C++ programs. For this, I need to query the heap for how much memory it has allocated. What’s a good way to do this? Or maybe a replacement allocator library that supports this efficiently?

Comment: What memory allocator implementation are you using?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Just the standard clang libc++, but I’m open to any options.

Comment: Do you need to be able to query memory usage from within your program, or would it be sufficient to use an external tool to measure heap usage of a given program (e.g. Valgrind's massif tool)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gperftools` has a cross-platform API to query the currently allocated bytes counter, among other things, in its [malloc_extension.h](https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools/blob/master/src/gperftools/malloc_extension.h), a part of its `tcmalloc` allocator. This should work for me, but I welcome other answers.